# How do I drop things in the Gungeon?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

What are the controls for dropping weapons, active items, and passive items?

The Controller inputs are listed in the game's options menu, but the keyboard+mouse controls are not.

Comment: Side note: "in the Gungeon" is in the question title because "How do I drop things?" is already a question for StarDew Valley and you're not allowed to have duplicate question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check keyboard + mouse bindings in the options menu, the default should be holding F to drop your gun and holding G to drop an item.

Comment: I feel dumb, apparently I kept missing the Keyboard Input controls on the menu and kept hitting the P1 Controller Settings.