# What are all of the controls?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I just purchased this game and I'd like to know ALL of the controls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I drop things in the Gungeon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261932/how-do-i-drop-things-in-the-gungeon)

Comment: @Riftcaster There's no way these are duplicates.

Comment: @Frank Reading the contents of the other question, they kind of are. The other question is just titled poorly, imo

Comment: @Ktash They're both asking for controls, but the duplicate is only asking for specific ones.  This one is asking for each and every one.  If we had more details, we might be able to dupe it, but as it stands, there's no way they're dupes.

Comment: @Frank At the end of the other question it does sort of ask how to find out all the controls. And the answer does answer this question. My take on it is that the other should have a more general title based on my reading of the content, and that they are dupes. But that's just my two cents

Comment: @Ktash You'd have to interpret that one pretty darn loosely to see this as duplicates.  I'd agree a more general question would be a good thing, but right now, I can't agree these are duplicates in any sense.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the recommended binding presets for both keyboard and controller.

**Keyboard**
[image]

**Controller**
[image]

Comment: Did you feel the need to put in keyboard aswell? Look below your answer..

Comment: I provided both keyboard and controller for completeness and readability. Although you did provide the information I didn't find it very easy to read as text alone.

Answer (score -1):

You can check keyboard + mouse bindings in the options menu, this should allow you to fully check "ALL" the game's controls..

Shoot - Left Click
Dodge Roll - Right Click
Interact - E
Reload - R
Move Up - W
Move Down - S
Move Left - A
Move Right - D
Use Item - Space
Use Blank - Q
Map - Tab
Next Gun - PositiveScrollWheel
Previous Gun - NegativeScrollWheel
Next Item - Left Shift
Previous Item - No Key Bound
Gun Menu - Control (Ctrl)
Drop Gun (Hold) - F
Drop Item (Hold) - G
Pause - Escape (Esc)
Inventory - I

(BTW I got all of these controls from the keyboard bindings in the options menu)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, except in passing.  He's asking what the controls *are*, not where to find them.

Comment: I think I've answered the question in my latest edit thank you very much

Comment: You've listed four keys.  That's nowhere near all the controls.

Comment: @Frank so, do you think the OP is actually gonna give the "Best Answer" to anyone?

Comment: Probably not.  I'm not sure why that's important, though.

Comment: reputation is good

Comment: Then try to put more effort into your contributions.  You will gain more reputation much easier.

Comment: I think this answer is fine. As long as the game allows you to configure your own keybindings, it is very much meaningless to tell a player what the controls are, since they are not necessarily the only set of controls. And also: Give a man a fish and teach a man to fish and all that etc.